# I am getting an error while importing BIRT report to Maximo: bmxaa5457e

Tags: eclipse, report, birt, maximo

I am getting an error while importing a BIRT report to Maximo.

The error is

```
bmxaa5457e   -  The report import process failed. Verify the specified information is correct before proceeding again.
```

Note that report is correct, I got a correct preview in Eclipse. There is nothing like images or other properties related to report.

[This](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/24236-import-failed/) didn't work. Java 2 security checkbox is also [unchecked](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=226435).

Comment: Did you solve this or not?

Comment: I solved the problem but sadly, I forgot to add the solution here and I don't remember the solution after 3 years, I am sorry. I should have acted more responsibly.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Eclipse BIRT are you using to design the reports and what version of BIRT does your Maximo support?  The issue might be that you're creating reports in a newer version than your Maximo supports.

Comment: thanks for your answer, we solved the problem. I will add it here, after I go to work.